# Why does Visual Studio want to link to glut32.lib while I have configured the project to use FreeGlut?

Tags: visual-studio, glut, freeglut

I am trying to compile a very old Win32 Visual Studio project (likely built in 2010) which requires either GLUT (3.7) or freeglut (2.4).

I downloaded freeglut and added additional paths for include and lib directories of this project to point to the freeglut include and lib.

However, I got one erro "LNK1104: cannot open file glut32.lib"

Why does Visual Studio want to link to glut32.lib (which belongs to GLUT) while I have configured the project to use FreeGlut?

I have tried to put glut32.lib in the lib path, but it only generates more errors.

Comment: Where did you download it? Was it [here](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/)? Are you using static libraries?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the Freeglut 3.0.0 MSVC Package from the website you linked. Thank you!

Comment: With MSVC, I have successfully made the project with, `#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK`, `#define FREEGLUT_STATIC`, `#include <GL/freeglut.h>`.